# How long have my Google Play subscribers been subscribers?

Tags: google-play

Google will now take 15%, not 30% perecent, for subscriptions that have lasted for over a year. See [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en).

We want to know how many people of our subscribers this affects.

I have found [this API call](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products) but it doesn't seem to give us all our subscribers.

Is there a way to find out how long our subscribers have been subscribed for? We want to use this information for accounting.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Play Develop API's [Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get). A successful call returns a [Purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) file resource which contains `startTimeMillis`:

> **startTimeMillis**   long    Time at which the subscription was granted, in milliseconds since the Epoch.

which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Sadly this isn't the case. This only lists one subscription, not all of them.